# No web.xml when overlaying Apereo CAS 5

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web.xml, cas

I overlayed  CAS 4.x (tried x=1 and 2) and the war is working perfectly, the web.xml is being downloaded and war is being deployed.

However, when running CAS 5.0.3.1 and higher versions, there is no web.xml in the overlayed war that is being prepared.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your issue. But if the project complains about missing web.xml, you can configure maven to NOT fail on missing web xml as below: <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

Comment: It's not an issue. Infact the property was already there. The issue is running the war made in tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution : It was extremely stupid of me to presume a Spring boot application would have a web.xml.

I'm supposed to run the war like a regular jar :

```
java - jar cas.war
```

And not inside a web application container.